# Is there a standard I can test a ECDH against?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman

I have a program in Python to do the ECDH with the NIST P-256 curve. The program is seemingly working, ie I get the same private key pair at the end. But I want to make sure it's not a coincidence in my code, and that my double-and-add algorithm is working correctly.

**TLDR:** Is there a strong curve that gives all the details like the NIST P-256 curve and also a tested 2 integers that give a specific private key pair?

Answer (score 2):

In [RFC 5114 appendix A.6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5114.html#appendix-A.6) there are test data for NIST P-256. Other appendices give other examples for other NIST curves.

If you want a different family [RFC 7027 appendix 1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7027.html#appendix-A.1) has test data for the brainpoolP256r1 curve and the other appendices give other examples.